# How to handle ORA-28002 without breaking the login cred check?

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, powershell, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been writing the powershell script to check login creds , but it shows gives 1 while checking for creds and gives below error-

ORA-28002: the password will expire within 6 days

I tried to catch it but even if we do so we will not be able to suppress this error and let it continue the checking cred

I tried to use  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue but this will not let my creds verify .. it will stop the error but not let my code keep checking if the creds are valid or not

=============CODE==============

```
function UserLoginCheck_Oracle($userName, $userPassword) 
{

   $IsLoggedIn = .\Tools\DBinstaller\DBinstaller.exe -port 1521 -type Oracle  -db xxxx -user $userName -password $userPassword -server xx.xx.xx.xxx -s "select 1 from dual" -silent   -ErrorAction Stop  

  if ($IsLoggedIn  -ne  1)
   { 
    $IsLoggedIn   
   }
```

===========================

Expected result -

I want my code to check for creds even this error occurs and not just terminate when this error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORA-28002 is a warning, so you should still be getting the `1` you expect after that appears. So, you can filter that specific message out:

```
$IsLoggedIn = .\Tools\DBinstaller\DBinstaller.exe -port 1521 -type Oracle  -db xxxx -user $userName -password $userPassword -server xx.xx.xx.xxx -s "select 1 from dual" -silent   -ErrorAction Stop `
  | Select-String -Pattern "ERROR:","ORA-28002: the password will expire within .* days" -NotMatch
```

You might also have blank lines that need to be suppressed.

---

If you want to preserve the error you could use multiple variable:

```
   $Result = .\Tools\DBinstaller\DBinstaller.exe -port 1521 -type Oracle  -db xxxx -user $userName -password $userPassword -server xx.xx.xx.xxx -s "select 1 from dual" -silent   -ErrorAction Stop
   $IsLoggedIn = ${Result} | Select-String -Pattern "ERROR","ORA-28002: the password will expire within .* days" -NotMatch
   $Warning = ${Result} | Select-String -Pattern "ORA-28002: the password will expire within .* days"

  if ($Warning  -ne  "")
   {
     $Warning
   }
  if ($IsLoggedIn  -ne  1)
   { 
    $IsLoggedIn   
   }
```

Comment: is there a way by which I can print this " the password will expire within .* days" and then continue?  Your answer is absolutely correct but what if we want to warn by just printing it first and then doing it? Do we need split function to check from the $IsLoggedIn and then continue?

Comment: I guess so, but I'm not sure the best way to do it, I'm not that familiar with PowerShell really. In general I'd get the full response as a variable, then pull just that message out (if it exists) into one new variable, and get a third which excludes it - which you can then check for the 1.

Comment: Yea,  that's what I was also thinking to use the split like function. Ok! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ParthoRocko - I've added a way that seems to work with just select-string.